# Как можно исправить ошибку в файле Effects11d.lib

Tags: c++, directx-11

Как можно исправить ошибку в файле Effects11d.lib?

```
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp___vsnprintf в функции "long __stdcall StringVPrintfWorkerA(char *,unsigned int,unsigned int *,char const *,char *)" (?StringVPrintfWorkerA@@YGJPADIPAIPBD0@Z)
```

Comment: Проверьте, собираете Вы Debug или Release и MT/MD

Answer (score 0):

Линкуемая библиотека была собрана старым компилятором и завязана на старые варианты crt, и для ее работы требуется костыль, заключающийся в подключении библиотеки `legacy_stdio_definitions.lib`. см [Overview of potential upgrade issues](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/overview-of-potential-upgrade-issues-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019#libraries).

Однако более правильным решением будет взять [опенсорсный вариант фреймворка FX11](https://github.com/microsoft/FX11) и собрать его самостоятельно. Или использовать какое-то свое решение так как FX не отличается гибкостью.

Comment: Сейчас выводится новая ошибка

Comment: Ошибка LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory@24 в функции "public: __thiscall Effect::Effect(struct ID3D11Device *,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &)" (??0Effect@@QAE@PAUID3D11Device@@ABV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить?